# Python 1 second clock timer

Tags: python

I have a Threaded timer that fires every second and updates a clock, the problem is that sometimes the clock will appear to be unstable and it can jump 2 seconds instead of a steady 1 second increment.

The problem of course is that the initial (or subsequent) timer is not triggered at exactly 0:000 seconds and therefore it is possible that updates to the clock appear to jitter.

Is there any way of preventing this ?

```
from threading import Timer
def timer():
  Timer(1.00, timer).start()
  STAT['ftime'] = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: is `Timer` `threading.Timer`?

Comment: Yes, sorrie, I will update..

Answer (score 0):

```
start_time = time.time()
interval = 1
for i in range(20):
    time.sleep(start_time + i*interval - time.time())
    # do a thing
```

Replace '20' with however many seconds you want to time.

Answer (score 0):

There are various approaches how to schedule, some designs may even provide measures to be able to deliver some acceptable kind of remedy for a blocked / failed initiation on a planned scheduling time-line -- what may help is finer timing / hierarchical timing / external synchronisation / asynchronous operations.

Without more details, there would be a poor practice to "*recommend*", but one may get ispired:

- if RealTime constraints allow to bear a bit more overhead, one may go to a "supersampled" elastic, failure-resilient scheduling scenario, so as to avoid a 2 second gap ( in case of a failed one **`.Timer()`** initiation ), where **`threading.Timer()`** model fires each 50 msec, and an embedded logic decides, if it is the *right-time* ( not farther than a half of one scheduling interval from an idealised one second edge ) and does the real-job, that was intended to be run, or just `return`, in case the RTC is not "near" the planned idealised scheduling time.
- a good python design also cannot forget about problems with **`GIL`**-lock issues, with avoiding blockingIO(s), with implementing a reasonable task-segmentation for CPU-bound parts of the code